# Как отправить запрос на другой сайт?

Tags: ajax, веб-программирование

У меня имеется форма на своем сайте, одно поле, когда я ввёл и отправил, то что я ввел, должно подставляться после слэша, вот так: test.ru/тут_что_я_ввел а если поле пустое, то соответственно ничего не поставлять и нужно получить ответ, он виде json, хочу отправить на ajax, заголовок на test.ru имеется
Как отправить? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Точно так же, как и на свой сайт, как и любой другой ajax-запрос. У вас какая-то проблема с отправкой ajax-запросов?

Comment: вот так? $.ajax({ 
            url: 'test.ru', 
            type: 'post', 
            data: data, 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: data => { 
                console.log(data); 
            } 
        })

Comment: И то есть, когда я отправлю на своем сайте форму, то запрос будет такой? test.ru/cheidjdh

Comment: Ну для начала определитесь, что куда вы хотите подставить. Вопрос выглядит так, будто вы хотите подставить что-то в url, а в этом коде вы зачем-то подставляете в data. Возможно, вам нужно изучить разницу между get и post запросами?